# How can i fix these missing vertices?

Tags: vertices, sculpting

This is my first time ever using blender, or any other 3D software (aka i have no idea what im doing). im following blender guru's donut tutorial on youtube (part 5: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_OrMDOK-Og). I did the steps at 0:52 before i realized some vertices where missing, i think, im really not sure what happened. Here is a picture:[image]

I tried undoing it as much as i can but i ran out of ctrl+z's. the shrinkwrap and solidify layers are applied onto the subdivision layer. The missing vertices only show up in edit mode. here is what it looks like in object mode:[image]

since it doesnt really change how it looks on object mode, im wondering if this even poses a problem.

Edit: Nevermind I found the solution. Some vertices were accidentally hidden and i didnt realize. I unhid them and everything was back to normal. I feel silly now, thanks for those who tried to help

Comment: Use the fill tool (f) in between the vertices where you want faces.

Comment: If you look in the Modifier Options, there's an icon that looks like a little computer monitor (above the "Si" of the word simple in your image) - this turns off (toggles) the modifier visibility in the viewport - turning them off will let you see what's going on better.

Comment: Using the fill tool made it look weird and lumpy, which looks even worse in object mode.

Toggling the modifier visibility off looks about the same as it was with it toggled on. from what i can tell, theres a missing vertex in the middle. Is it possible to add a vertex in the middle and connect it to the ones around it?

Comment: @robomess Yes, you can fill in between just two opposing vertices to make an edge across the center of the gap, then loop cut it so that there is a vertex in the middle of that edge. Use the fill tool in between the center vertex and the two other vertices on either side so that there is an edge coming from each vertex into the middle. Fill in between each square of four edges to make four faces where your gap was. Do this to the other side as well. If it looks too flat, you can move the center vertex outward to make it look rounder. Be sure to shade smooth afterward.

Comment: You might want to Delete your question?

Comment: You may want to keep your question.  You mentioned the video website above.   I would suggest seeing more intro novice videos.  A video series would be good for you.  Also you can consider a Bundt cake rather than a donut.   Go Big.  Real Big.

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem, however, I'll give the same advice I always give regarding the donut tutorial - _Every_ time you make a mistake, or things don't turn out right, close the program (no saving) and start over from the very beginning. It might seem like a pain, but the repetition will make you much faster and more comfortable with blender's systems. By the end, you'll be able to do the entire donut scene in less than 10 mins with no guidance.